# Django Issue Template Does Not Exist at /deals/

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am new Django user. When I run program in Django I got this error please help.

```
Template Does Not Exist at /deals/

{'form': <DealsForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(name;pages;email)>}
```

view.py

```
class DealsForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ['name','pages','email']

def deals(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    form = DealsForm()

    context = {'products': products}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DealsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('products/deals')
    else:
        form = DealsForm()
        return render('products/deals.html',{'form': form}, context_instance=context)
```

Comment: Try changing the last line to `return render(request, 'products/deals.html', context)` and add the form variable to your context dictionary

Comment: Hi Jean! Thanks for your reply. Its working. Error is solved but here I have a form in deals.html which is not display.

Comment: Here its code        <form action="/deals/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
</form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was the arguments to the `render` function, it waits parameters like

`render(request, 'name_of_template.html', context_dict)`

Also, check your `form` variable it must be inside of the `context` dictionary, try adding it this way before pass it to render:

`context['form'] = form`

These things should work now.